# SFTP error - Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: java

```
private SSHClient initSSHj(String remoteHost, String username, String password)
      throws IOException {
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(remoteHost);
    client.authPassword(username, password);
    return client;
  }    

protected void uploadFile(
  String localFilePath,
  String remoteHost,
  String username,
  String remotePassword,
  String remoteFilePath) {
try {
  SSHClient sshClient = initSSHj(remoteHost, username, remotePassword);
  SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();
  sftpClient.getFileTransfer().setPreserveAttributes(false);
  sftpClient.put(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
  sftpClient.close();
  sshClient.disconnect();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  log.info("Error file to the server :: {}", ex.getMessage());
  throw new Exception("Error file to the server");
}
```

}

The error

{"@timestamp":"2022-02-11T19:38:43.867+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Received SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT (reason=BY_APPLICATION, msg=)","logger_name":"net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl","thread_name":"reader","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2022-02-11T19:38:43.868+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Dying because - ","logger_name":"net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl","thread_name":"reader","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: \n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.gotDisconnect(TransportImpl.java:565)\n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:521)\n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decodeMte(Decoder.java:159)\n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:79)\n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:231)\n\tat net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:60)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-02-11T19:38:43.868+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION","logger_name":"net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl","thread_name":"reader","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}

I have checked username and password, there is no issue. I also have write permission to upload the file in sftp.

From the command line , same creds work for sftp connection.

Comment: Can you use sftp from the command line?

Comment: from command line , sftp connection works.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that it (the client) has tried all of the methods of authentication *that the server allows* (at this time / for this kind of connection) and exhausted them.

> Have checked username and password, there is no issue.

It may be that the server does not permit user/password authentication in this context.  Maybe it requires public key authentication.

(It is common practice to disallow user / password authentication when connecting to a public IP address.  Its a good way to eliminate the risk of hacking by password guessing.)

If you have (for example) `fail2ban` set up on the server, it may be that access is temporarily blocked due to too many recent failed attempts to login.

---

> Also have write permission to upload the file in sftp.

That won't be relevant.  The session hasn't gotten to the point where it needs to check file's permissions.

---

Check the server-side logs (e.g. the security log).  If there is nothing helpful there, you could try increasing the logging level on the server side (e.g. for `sshd`) to get more information about why the authentication is failing.